# How to move the progress bar to the page bottom in Qualtrics?

Tags: qualtrics

The original progress bar was at the page top in Qualtircs, I tried to move it to the center bottom of the page using `.Skin #ProgressBar{position: absolute;bottom:10px;right:10px;left:10px}`, It works for some pages but not for the ones which need to be scrolled down to see the whole page. From what I understand, the "bottom" means the relative end of a page but not the actual end, but I have no idea of how to change it to the actual end.

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. Please, could you provide some code of your specific problem. That prove how far did you try and it will help other members to understand your problem better, at the time, you will give them a context of your issue. Please, check these links: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve and https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 1):

Change 'absolute' to 'fixed'.

```
.Skin #ProgressBar{position: fixed;bottom:10px;right:10px;left:10px}
```